# cq5 not returning child pages json data on '...infinity.json' request

Tags: aem

Even though following path `http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/products.infinity.json` returning folllowing json.

[image]

But same page request in my upper environments (DEV, Stage, QA boxes) returning following json

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on this ? I am trying to read child pages data for one of the component and it is working great in local but not in upper environment boxes.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure both the requests are same. I guess in your local the request is http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/products.infinity.json whereas in the rest of the environments it is http://something.com/content/geometrixx/en/products/_jcr_content.infinity.json

Comment: @rakhi4110 yes only the host name changed, but rest of the path is same. It seems, .infinity.json turned off from allowable paths at dispatcher level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that these are stage / production instances, it's possible that additional security measures were taken. If you look at the security checklist, you will see it recommends limiting number of nodes exposed by the Sling Get Servlet [0]:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/security-checklist.html

So if the json.maximumresults property of the Apache Sling Get Servlet was set to 5, the page.infinity.json request won't return all the nodes in the tree.

If you have access to the instance's configuration manager (/system/console/configMgr), you can check the value of the json.maximumresults property for this servlet.

[0] https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-servlets-get/blob/dd8af0d1d4c9666ffb16d5324a47e41ba413d973/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/DefaultGetServlet.java#L126

Comment: 5 is not a number of levels in the tree, but maximum number of resources that should be returned, so the tree can be flat (just one level) and if the tree root node have more than 5 children then `infinity.json` requests will return links with pagination rather than the actual json content

Comment: Yup, you're right, @TomaszSzymulewski, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second response looks like you are hitting the jcr:content sub node directly

`/content/geometrixx/en/products/jcr:content.infinity.json`

The reason I say this, is that the response in your second request is the same as the graph beneath your jcr:content node in the first response.

If the request is the same, you might want to look at your resource mappings to see if something is modifying your request.